# Can a parent class array hold children class objects in Java?

Tags: java

I have a parent class named Student. I have created two children class PermanentStudent and CasualStudent by extending this. I have written constructors for both the extended child classes (both child class have their own constructors). Now, I am making an array of size 10 of Students out of which 4 will be Permanent Students and 6 will be CasualStudents. For this, I did as follows:

```
Student[] a = new Student[10];
int count;
```

Now, I wish to fill the array with 4 permanent students objects and 6 casual student objects with information through their constructor. I do the following,

```
for (count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    a[count] = new PermanentStudent(a,b,c); // invoking the constructor
}
for (count = 4; count < 10; count++)
{
    a[count] = new CasualStudent(x,y); // invoking the constructor of the other class
}
```

But this gives me a compilation error. Where am I going wrong in this? Thanks!

Comment: "Compilation error" is not very clear, can you tell me the error _message_?

Comment: What error message you getting

Comment: I am getting the error that this the constructor cannot be invoked for this class.

Comment: Can you add a summary of you class hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Assignment like `Base base = new Sub()` or `base[i] = new Sub()` in your case is legal in Java.
Problem is in your constructors, check no-arguments constructor exists in `Student`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this is a problem with the constructors and not the polymorphism itself (it works when I tested it?). Probably check to see that your constructor data types match up and there are no constructors to initialize in your superclass